# I want to create 64000 as fixed file length in as400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, cobol

I want to create fixed file length as 64000, but it throws error message like

> Numeric value for parameter RCDLEN is not valid

Comment: When including error messages in your posts, please use the full text, including the message reference.

Comment: You can't use a length > 32K for an undescribed file. A single fixed-length column must be < 32K in length, and the sum of fixed-length elements of a row of an externally-described file also must be < 32K. Use LOBs if it's required, or use a streamfile rather than a database file. IOW, use objects that are appropriate for whatever it is that you're doing.

Comment: Is possible to create file more than 32k length in as400.?

Comment: You can create files with row widths much larger than 32K. They just can't be fixed-length. Use various LOB columns for example.

Answer (score 5):

Just a simple overflow. From the doc:

> A value ranging from 1 through 32766 bytes can be specified for the record length.

64 000 is greater than 32766 that's why you get the error

Comment: how can i create file with fixed length value as 64000 ?

Comment: @Prawin I don't know. I would say that you can't but **I'm not sure**.

Comment: @Prawin it is set deep within the operating system. Having had your question answered, you should Accept the answer (see the outline tick near the answer) and ask a new question detailing why you need to have fixed-length records of 64000.

Comment: @Prawin Also only include the COBOL tag in your new question if it is relevant, and don't use the Mainframe tag, as you have already indicated ibm-midrage, so Mainframe must be wrong (unless you explain why a Mainframe is involved as well).

Answer (score 1):

```
CRTPF FILE(QTEMP/MYFILE) RCDLEN(64000)
```

Is not valid as you've found out.  As Thomas noted, the maximum value for RCDLEN is 32766.

```
CRTPF FILE(QTEMP/MYFILE) RCDLEN(32766)
```

However, note that the 32766 limitation doesn't come from the command itself; rather 32766 is the maximum length of a character column in the DB.  If you read the help for the CRTPF command, you'd find:

> Specifies the length (in bytes) of the records stored in the physical
>   file.  If RCDLEN and FILETYPE(*DATA) are    specified, the physical
>   file is created with a record    format that has only one field.

So you could using SQL create the very same file

```
create table myfile (
  myfile char(32766) for bit data
) rcdfmt myfile
```

But again, 32766 is the max size of a character column in DB2 for i.

However, the use of SQL opens up other possibilities. In your case, BLOB columns.

```
create table myfile (
  myfile blob(64000)
) rcdfmt myfile
```

BLOB is the direct equivalent to the FOR BIT DATA.  If dealing with character data, CLOB would be a better choice.

So there you go, a file with a fixed record length of 64000.  At least, kind of sort of.  The fact is, LOB columns are stored in the overflow space objects not the main data area of the table.

Why you'd want this or how you hope to be able to use it is another matter.

You can only access LOB objects with SQL operations.

Comment: A CLOB _might be_ a better choice than BLOB, but the OP would have to decide.